# How do I force a namespace for a helper from within a spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, rspec

I am trying to test the output of a view helper that resides within a namespace. The original helper is located under app/helpers/admin/events_helper.rb. The test is at spec/helpers/admin/events_helper_spec.rb and looks like this (simplified):

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../spec_helper'

describe Admin::EventsHelper do

  fixtures :events, :users

  before(:each) do
    @event = events(:one)
    @user = users(:one)
  end

  it "should include link to admin page for user" do
    html = helper.event_message(@event)
    html.should have_selector("a", :href => admin_user_path(@user))
  end

end
```

The helper, ridiculously simplified, looks like this:

```
module Admin::EventsHelper
  def event_message(event)
    link_to(
      event.message, 
      :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => event.user.id)
  end
end
```

When the event_message method is called from a controller within the Admin namespace, it renders the link as '/admin/users/:id' as intended. However, called from the spec, it renders as '/users/:id', making the test fail.

How do I specify the correct namespace to use for the helper within the spec?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem stems from the way Rspec (and the Rails test framework) handles controllers. For complex reasons (*OK, reasons I don't understand*), you don't get a real ActionController when testing, instead you get an instance of ActionView::TestCase::TestController. When using namespaces, the test controller in this case is not correctly inferring the actual controller path, so it guesses "/users", which is wrong.

Long story short, while there is probably a better way to do it, you can try stubbing out the controller method that gets called by `url_for` to generate the link:

```
it "should include link to admin page for user" do
  controller.stub(:url_options).and_return(:host=>"test.host", :protocol=>"http://", :_path_segments=>{:controller=>"admin/users", :action=>"show"}, :script_name=>"")
  html = helper.event_message(@event)
  html.should have_selector("a", :href => admin_user_path(@user))
end
```

Comment: That works, thanks. The _path_segment parameter is the only one I need, in fact. Cheers.

Comment: Interestingly, "admin/user" even works for other resources under the admin namespace. Just for giggles I replaced it with "admin/foo", and it still works. So I guess all it does is tell the controller to use the admin namespace when generating routes - just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question correct, you are asking about specifying the controller namespace which is failing in spec right?

If you UsersController is within Admin namespace, then you should be doing this:

`link_to(event.message, :controller => 'admin/users', :action => 'show', :id => event.user.id)` in your helper method.

Note the value for controller key is **`admin/users`**

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a controller spec but a helper spec. I'm not calling a controller method, I'm calling a helper method via the "helper" object, which is of class ActionView::Base. See the example at http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/dir/helper-specs/helper-spec